# MaxCharCount is not working in CKeditor5 ( React js)

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I'd like the user to be blocked from typing more if the value is over 100.
I'm using CKeditor5 in React js.

```
config.wordcount = {

// Whether or not you want to show the Paragraphs Count
showParagraphs: false,

// Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
showWordCount: false,

// Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
showCharCount: true,

// Whether or not you want to count Spaces as Chars
countSpacesAsChars: true,

// Whether or not to include Html chars in the Char Count
countHTML: false,

// Maximum allowed Word Count, -1 is default for unlimited
maxWordCount: 400,

// Maximum allowed Char Count, -1 is default for unlimited
maxCharCount: 400
};
```